# Has .toggle() been deprecated in the latest jQuery releases?

Tags: jquery

Can you tell me if `.toggle()` has been deprecated in latest releases?

In my code, this method works with the 1.7.2 library, but doesn't work with the latest.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: The method [is still there](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/), but an [old *signature*](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending jQuery , defining a `.toggleFn` function

```js
(function($) {
  
  jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleFn: function(fn1, fn2) {
      $.fn.toggleFn.index = fn = $.fn.toggleFn.index || 0;
      try {
        arguments[fn].call(this);
        $.fn.toggleFn.index = !fn ? 1 : void 0;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      };
      return this
    }
  });

  jQuery.extend({
    toggleFn: jQuery.fn.toggleFn
  });

}(jQuery));

$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleFn(function() {
    $(this).text("click " + 1)
  }, function() {
    $(this).text("click " + 0)
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click 0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own toggle function. It has indeed been deprecated. This replacement works just great.

```
$.fn.toggleClick=function(){
    var functions=arguments, iteration=0
    return this.click(function(){
        functions[iteration].call()
        iteration= (iteration+1) %functions.length
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
$( "#target" ).toggleClick(function() {
    alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
}, function() {
    alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
});
```

See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: i'm searching in google toggleClick() but i find nothing...

Answer (score 0):

It was deprecated it 1.8 and removed in 1.9 here is the documentation
http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Do you know another similiar method? thanks! :)

Comment: It wasn't deprecated, per se. One of its *signatures* (the arguments you pass to it) was deprecated.