# Setting and retrieving a variable with JQuery Toggle

Tags: jquery, css, variables, toggle

I am trying to use jQuery .toggle() to make a clicked image larger, then return to its original state (before the click) on the second click.

I have images arranged by packery.js, so each has a dynamically generated "absolute" inline style. I want to grab, store, then pass those values to the second toggle function to reapply to the image, so it "restores" to its original style and placement in the Packery container.  Here's my code now:

```
var thisStyle;

    $("img").click().toggle(
        function() {
            thisStyle = this.style;
            $(this).removeClass('item').addClass('item-big').center();},          
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('item-big').addClass('item').css({ thisStyle });
        }
        );
```

But when the second click happens, it seems to be updating "thisStyle" to have the img's style when its at the the larger size with the new class and styles from "item-big" (after the first click).

Is there a way to "freeze" or store the values of "thisStyle"/this.style (take a snapshot) to reuse later in the second toggle function?

Extra info -----------

this.style grabs the custom inline style for 'item', which in one case looks like this:

```
style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;"
```

this.style returns that style information as an Object.  Again, the problem is that when the variable that that is assigned to seems to update when used in the second toggle function.

.center() is a custom jQuery function that's doing some math to center the larger image on the first click/toggle function:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Comment: What is expected result of `thisStyle = this.style;` ? Which specific style properties of `img` should be stored at `thisStyle` ? What is `.center()` ? Can include `html`, `css` at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Sorry; I included some more extra info in the question, thanks!

Comment: Which version of jQuery is used for `js` at Question ?

Comment: I'm using version 1.11.13: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: _"using version 1.11.13:"_ Appear to be using deprecated `.toggle()` at Question ? See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ , http://stackoverflow.com/q/31899245/ . Tried `thisStyle = $(this).css(["position", "left", "top"]);` ? To reset style `$(this).removeClass('item-big').addClass('item').css( thisStyle );` , without `{}` within `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

> using version 1.11.13

Appear to be using deprecated version `.toggle()` at Question ? See

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) , [Has .toggle() been deprecated in the latest jQuery releases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31899245) .

Try utilizing `.css()`  `thisStyle = $(this).css(["position", "left", "top"]);`

```js
var thisStyle;
$("img").click(
    function() {
      thisStyle = $(this).css(["position", "left", "top"]);
      console.log(thisStyle);          
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats" class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;" />
```

Comment: .toggle() is still working for me... forgot that I was also using `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` which I think is allowing the use of older functions, and makes the newer jQuery work in older browsers?  I tried your suggestion too, and it works perfectly. Many thanks!