# How do I turn this jQuery function into an 'if' statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Right now I'm trying to write a jquery function which lets me expand a div when you click it, then return it to its initial size when you click it again.

I tried adding a button to make it retract, but because when I click it the script thinks I'm also clicking the parent div and expands again. Ideally, I'd like to do it without having a button.

The code I've got is here -

(jsfiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/Nikf/wykL6u7u/9/

```
<div class="grid">
        <div class="block" id="block1">
            <button class="retractor" id="ret1">back</button>
        </div>
        <div class="block" id="block2">2</div>
        <div class="block" id="block3">3</div>
        <div class="block" id="block4">4</div>
        <div class="block" id="block5">5</div>
        <div class="block" id="block6">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background-color: #114411;*/
}

.block{
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.retractor{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}

#block1{
    background-color: #222222;
}           

#block2{
    background-color: #999999;
}           

#block3{
    background-color: #5555555;
}           

#block4{
    background-color: #999999;
}   

#block5{
    background-color: #333333;
}       

#block6{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
```

Script

```
$('#block1').click(function(){
    $('#block1').animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    });
});

$('#block1').click(function(){
    $('#block1').animate({
        width: '33.3%',
        height: '50%'
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code on JSFiddle and the code posted here are different.

Comment: why shouldn't it? you're attaching both of your click handlers to the same "parent" div. Your "close" click handler should be attached to `#ret1` instead.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah that's a massive mistake on my part. I'd copy-pasted the script from an earlier JSFiddle. The updated version has the click handler attached to ret1

Comment: In this example you are better off using CSS animation and simply toggle a class on the element... like @Sebastian Wramba posted 2 seconds before I suggested this :)

Comment: SO community elders, the question title seems misleading - this doesn't have much to do with an "if statement" but rather with applying/removing styling and animation.  What do you think of a rephrasing like "How do I toggle these elements styling and animation" to make it clearer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jQuery `toggleClass` in combination with CSS transitions to get the same result. Check https://jsfiddle.net/wykL6u7u/11/ and see if that fits your needs.

What I've done:

```
.block {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 50%;
// ...
  transition: all 1s;
}

.block.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

And the JS is just the class toggle:

```
$('#block1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

Comment: You need to add the cross-browser compatibility styles, but otherwise cool :)

Comment: All browsers support the non-prefixed version of this for quite some time now. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) Of course, if you absolutely must support older versions, this is necessary.

Comment: All "new" browsers support the non-prefixed version of this. There is unfortunately still a lot of old browser versions in use (usually in places with security concerns, or can't afford to upgrade every PC yet). I say hope for the future, but code for the real world :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using "toggleClass" and relying on CSS classes rather than hard-coded CSS values. Agree with @sebastian-wramba

The thing is we don't really need the back button here at all. I took it out with the understanding that op would prefer it not being in there but that the click on the div do the toggle.  Feedback welcome if I'm not reading the requirements correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/e15kxkdr/3/

```
<div class="grid">
      <div class="block" id="block1">1</div>
      <div class="block" id="block2">2</div>
      <div class="block" id="block3">3</div>
      <div class="block" id="block4">4</div>
      <div class="block" id="block5">5</div>
      <div class="block" id="block6">6</div>
</div>

.grid{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background-color: #114411;*/
}

.block{
    width: 33.3%;
  height: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}
.nodisplay {
  display: none;

}

$('.grid').on("click", "div", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("grid")
        $(this).toggleClass("block")
        $(this).siblings().toggleClass("nodisplay")
    })
```

Update:  I changed this to work off the children of the main element "grid" via the jquery "[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)" subelement rather than using a separate class.  Then I added a new class "nodisplay" to hide the other elements.

Comment: The back button still bounces.

Comment: Ok, neglected to cover that as a requirement.

Comment: You managed to get an upvote on a broken answer... you might want to fix it to earn that :)

Comment: Ok will do @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Need to update your JSFiddle to match your changes. The CSS animation styling is critical to this working.

Comment: Better?  Appreciate the mentoring re answers, this question has enough attention already so this is more Q/A practice for me.  Better to spread my newbness all over questions in more need of the effort

Comment: This one only seems to work if you click on grid block 1....i assume it has to do with the CSS involved but im not sure. I tried making the click binding on `.block` and it still only truly worked on block 1

Comment: The difference is you need a selector across elements that stays consistent.  Since the block class has the formatting tied to it, you need a different class as the selector.

Comment: Updated answer to work across all the block elements by using jquery on delegation

Comment: Delegation is not required if the elements are static, but it is more efficient. +1 for the technique (even if the reason given is not correct). :)

Comment: Can you clarify which reason I gave that was incorrect - the comment or the post update?  Do you mean the comment "you need a different class as the selector"?  I chose to use delegation rather than class selector since the CSS class is already loaded with the styling/animation

Comment: No biggie. You implied that delegation was *required*: `"to work across all the block elements by using jquery on delegation"`. I was clarifying that was not the case (as you could have done it with `click`), but it *is* a better way to code multiple elements. :)

Comment: Ah ok.  Many thanks for the expansion/clarification!

Answer (score 1):

So after thinking it over I did it this way. It does 2 calculations to find out the percentage of the width and height of the grid and does an animate based on that. I have it set to expand and contract based on the grid click but if you want to use the button just change the click binding back to the back buttons id.

```
$('.grid').click( function() {
  var heightPercentage = ( 100 * parseFloat($('.grid').css('height')) / parseFloat($('.grid').parent().css('height')) ) + '%';  
  var widthPercentage = ( 100 * parseFloat($('.grid').css('width')) / parseFloat($('.grid').parent().css('width')) ) + '%'; 
  var toggleWidth = widthPercentage === "100%" ? "33%" : "100%";
  var toggleHeight = heightPercentage === "100%" ? "50%" : "100%";
  $('.grid').animate({ 
    width: toggleWidth,
    height: toggleHeight
  });       
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgarrison25/o7k2y25q/1

Comment: That one works... why not post that one instead of the broken link? Never mind, already changed it for you +1 for the effort (now it works) :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...im working at the same time as im answering....probably not the best combination... technically you could remove the appending of the percent sign and then check for "100" instead of "100%" but I figured for readability sake it wasn't a big deal

Comment: BTW the reason I prefer this as opposed to the selected answer is because I would rather have the backwards compatibility that Jquery offers instead of dealing with all the css3 transition compatibility issues.

Comment: If you use the cross-browser settings, CSS transition goes back quite a way. I agree if you need to go a long way back you need a code solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var expand = true;
     $('#block1').click(function(){
         var width='33.3%', height="50%";
         if(expand){
            width='100%';
            height='100%';
            expand=false;
         }else{
            expand=true;
         }
        $('#block1').animate({
           width: width,
           height: height
        });
     });

});
```

Comment: I added else statement. Now it's working perfectly :) thanks!

Comment: Much better... Personally I dislike using local variables to hold animation state. You also need to stop any existing animation in the queue (click really fast to see) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try storing values in an array, using `Array.prototype.reverse()`

> I think @BillGarrison is correct. Without explanation it is not
>   obvious how the code works.

Explanation:

Approach is a "toggle" procedure. Use value at `arr[0]` for a process; reverse `arr`; use value at `arr[0]` for next process; reverse `arr`.

The approach could be implemented without using `Array.prototype.reverse()`; using `0` and `1` , `undefined`; see [Has .toggle() been deprecated in the latest jQuery releases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899245/toggle-in-latest-jquery-releases-has-been-deprecated-beacause-doesnt-work).

Approach could also be extended to cycle through, or toggle `n` values in succession, returning to initial value once all array items are iterated.

```
    var arr = [
      ["100%", "100%"],
      ["33.3%", "50%"]
    ];

    $("#block1").click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
            // at initial click, set `width` to `arr[0][0]` : `100%`,
            // set `height` to `arr[0][1]` : `100%`
            // reverse `arr`
            // at second click `arr[0]` : `["33.3%", "50%"]`;
            // set `width` to `arr[0][0]` : `33.3%`
            // set `height` to `arr[0][1]` : `50%`;
            // repeat procedure
            width: arr[0][0],
            height: arr[0][1]
          }, function() {
            arr.reverse()
          });
    })
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wykL6u7u/14/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you change the logic. It is easier if you add a specific class and let the CSS do the animation.

```
$('.block').click(function(ev){
    $(ev.target).toggleClass('active');
});
```

This way you can remove the button from the .block elements.

Add the animation and the new class to the CSS:

```
.block{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.block.active{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I haven't tested this code. I hope it works

--EDIT--

ev.target is not a jQuery element. I wrapped it in $(ev.target) otherwise it didn't have .toggleClass();

Comment: Please add your example to a JSFiddle. I still can't get this one to work.